# sending signal on when for/in loop has completed all iterations

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, for-in-loop

I have an array of objects which I am using a for/in loop to manipulate into key/value pairs, which as it works writes each to a database.

My app is designed to send a push notification when the database is updated, which works as intended, but when there are multiple items in the loop it will send a notification per each of these objects (expected, but not so intended)

My simple loop code is:

```
for(var idx in multiSelectSaveArr) {
            calendarPage.saveCalendarMultiItem(time = multiSelectSaveArr[idx].creationDate, multiSelectSaveArr[idx])

        }
```

The purpose of this is that `time` will become the unique key, whilst the value is a JSON object.

my `calendarPage.saveCalendarMultiItem` is a signal to my dataModel, which is where the function to store the data is, so each iteration then calls a function which handles the database writing as an individual object

The nature of my loop is that sometimes it could contain 3 objects, other times 30 - it is a different number each time.

**My Question Is**

Is there a way I can signal the end of the loop, meaning once the final object has been iterated through to then only send a single notification?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach` to check the index and get the array value during iteration, once the `idx` is at the last but one index you call you notification function to signal the iteration is over:

```
multiSelectSaveArr.forEach(function(val, idx){
   calendarPage.saveCalendarMultiItem(time = val.creationDate, val);
   if(idx === multiSelectSaveArr.length - 1) notificationCallback();
}
```

You can also do it using `Array.prototype.entries` and the `for..of` loop which is designed for iteration of an *iterable* like an array:

```
for(const [idx, val] of multiSelectSaveArr.entries()){
   calendarPage.saveCalendarMultiItem(time = val.creationDate, val);
   if(idx === multiSelectSaveArr.length - 1) notificationCallback();
}
```

The reason I am calling the `notificationCallback()` inside the loop along with the `if` condition is because I assume *you won't send the notification* if the array is *empty*, if I placed the callback call after the loop it would've worked regardless and also it didn't require an `if`, but that would still call the `notificationCallback()` although the loop never ran.

Do not use `for..in` loop to iterate over the array as it iterates over property values of an object (in this case an array object) in an unspecified order.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) for more details.

Comment: Hi and thanks so much for the answer! I am not working with ECMAScript 6 as my version of Qt does not support them! am I right in saying changing that section from `=>` to `function() {..restOfCode..}` would resolve this?

Comment: @Ldweller yes that will also work, please accept the answer if it helped you!

Comment: a quick conversion comes up as `multiSelectSaveArr.forEach(function (val, idx) {
                calendarPage.saveCalendarMultiItem(time = val.creationDate, val);
                if (idx === multiSelectSaveArr.length - 1)
                    notificationCallback();
            });` in case you want to update the answer with previous compatibilities!